How to "import personalized element-kit" in elementor plugin
I'm trying to personalized a theme for my job, for speed up the process of production of website.
Trying to personalize with a function, the page of Elementor > Export/Import elements-kit, adding a dropdown list of my elements-kit stored in a local folder to import directly on wordpress.
or if possible replicate the function of elementor to import the kit like an Astra personalized theme...
anyone have advice?
I've created a personalized dashboard in wordpress that appears after the installation of the theme and the required plugins, in the dashboard it's only showed up which are the personalized elements-kit (restaurant-kit, business-kit) but i don't how to get further...
